# Let $y,z$ be two functions such that $y=zf(y)$ where $f$ is a power series wrt $y$. Then we can find of powers series for any $g(y)$

Tags: analysis, power-series

Let $y,z$ be two functions such that $y=zf(y)$ where $f$ is a power series with respect to $y$. Then we can write any $g(y)$ as a power series of $z$ such that

$g(y)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}\bigg( \big(f(y)^kg^{'}(y)\big)^{(k-1)}\bigg|_{y=0}\bigg)z^k$.

(Here, $^{(k-1)}$, $k-1$-th derivative and $g$ is a function which all derivative exist.)

Comment: Hello - would you explain why this statement matters and whether it is true or false?

Comment: Hi, it is true.

For any one who interest: Edouard Goursat, A course in mathematical analysis,1904. Can check  section 9, pg.189.

Comment: Thank you. Now why should one be interested in this?

Comment: We can calculate $p-$adic behavior of some function with using this function. This allows us to know it for some nice functions. I used it to calculate but it was complicated in the book I wrote. But the answer shows it is not complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems related to Lagrange Burmann series:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInversionTheorem.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem

Comment: Thanks for related webpages.